# merging sheets from left to right, not top down using range method

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

i just like to open several source files (all excel) and always copy the complete data rom sheet 1 into my target-sheet. First part works well.

The unusual thing is that i want the tables to be merged from the left to right (horizontical), not from top down. 
Of course the range needs to adjust dynamically. The allocation part is also working. Whats not working is to copy it over my target sheet and always add from left to right.

Means 
Worksheet 1 hast data from A1:C10 
Worksheet 2 has data from A1:B20

should be merged like

Worksheet 1 hast data from A1:C10 -> A1:C10
Worksheet 2 has data from A1:B20 -> D1:E20

etc. I cannot do this. It either gives me a 1004, or says that the object doesnt support the method.

Here's the code:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Das "Flackern" ausstellen

 Set oTargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
 lErgebnisSpalte = 1

 sPfad = "C:\Users\TEST\"
 sDatei = Dir(CStr(sPfad & "*.xl*")) 

 Do While sDatei <> ""


     Set oSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(sPfad & sDatei, False, True) 
     z1 = oSourceBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
         s1 = oSourceBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

**oSourceBook.Sheets(1).Range(oSourceBook.Cells(1, 1), oSourceBook.Cells(z1, s1)).Copy oTargetSheet.Range(oTargetSheet.Cells(1, lErgebnisSpalte), oTargetSheet.Cells(z1, s1))**

    lErgebnisSpalte = lErgebnisSpalte + 1
    oSourceBook.Close False 'nicht speichern

     'Next File
     sDatei = Dir()
 Loop

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Das Bildschirm-Aktualisieren wieder einschalten

 'Variablen aufräumen
 Set oTargetSheet = Nothing
     Set oSourceBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Debug keeps saying: 
Object doesnt support the method; and marks this line:

```
**oSourceBook.Sheets(1).Range(oSourceBook.Cells(1, 1), oSourceBook.Cells(z1, s1)).Copy oTargetSheet.Range(oTargetSheet.Cells(1, lErgebnisSpalte), oTargetSheet.Cells(z1, s1))**
```

Comment: Hi @armInluz welcome to **StackOverflow** , why don't you use `Range("").End(xlToRight).Select`

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ
thanks for the hint. Could try but i still need to determine variable where to paste the data. It needs to be one coloumn after where the last c/p ended 

first table; A1 to C20, next D1 to L:50; next M1 to N160 etc etc. Otherwise it will simply overwrite the data i like to merge into one sheet

Comment: In german again :)

Es hilft mir dahingehend nicht, da immer die Daten aus dem jeweils nächsten Kopiervorgang nach Ende des alten anfangen müssen. So könnte ich ggf. die Range dynamisch selektieren - aber wie füge ich die dann in einer schleife immer in einem leeren bereich ein?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (in this case I just copy the existing range into the next free column)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim colNr As Integer

For i = 1 To 100
colNr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
colNr = colNr + 1
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNr)
Next i
End Sub
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: No sorry it doesnt work either, xltoRight reports 16385 cells... so the total amount, not the used ones 
Also i do not have a fixed source range. I'm importing 10 different files with complete different ranges.

Comment: You can always redefine your range. It shouldn't give you all the cells as it checks the number of last written column on the right side. I add one to that which means it enters the first empty column on the right side.

Comment: Thanks pal, 
However pls look at

`sPfad = "C:\Users\TEST\"
 sDatei = Dir(CStr(sPfad & "*.xl*")) 

 Do While sDatei <> ""
     Set oSourceBook = Workbooks.Open(sPfad & sDatei, False, True)` 

i like to open several files with several dynamic ranges. I cannot hardcode the range into the source code, the range needs to be determined for each loop. 
That however is working by count used range. The copy over to my new file is not working, always says object doesnt support method or 1004 error. 
Keep in mind, paste area also needs to change each loop :) (the used coloumn)

Comment: You can set a new range every loop. The first thing you do is determine the range, next you add one by that to get to the next column and you paste it. Next loop you overwrite the range with the new range (old range + new pasted data). If you check every loop what your range is you can always get to the next column. I edited my example.